# QgsDistanceArea computeSpheroidProject return 0, 0

Tags: python-3.x, qgis

I want to poject a point in QGis in a distance, I am using QGis 3.4 with python but it is not returning the correct point projected

```
d = QgsDistanceArea()
p = QgsPointXY(-123.26,49.06)
nuevoPunto = d.computeSpheroidProject(p,10,0)
print(nuevoPunto.x(),nuevoPunto.y())
```

Output:

```
0.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an Ellipsoid. For example:

```
d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
p = QgsPointXY(-123.26,49.06)
nuevoPunto = d.computeSpheroidProject(p,10,0)
```

This should work; it did for me.